# d3 - <g> Group Element Height

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to clip an image into a circle within a group.
[image]

Here is the clip path code

```
<defs>
   <clipPath id="empImgClip">
      <circle r="53" cy="55" cx="55"></circle>
   </clipPath>
</defs>
```

The svg code as viewed in chrome console

[image]

The problem, as I understand, is that the edges of the circle are cliped by the `<g></g>` group element and is not apearing properly. One thing I came up with is to increase the height of the `<g>` and adjust the circle position but `<g>` takes its height autmatically based on the contents its wrapping.

I want the circle image to appear at the top left of the rounded 
rectangle with the center of the circle image exactly placed at the x0,y0 of the rectangle so that the circle image if half inside half outside the rectangle.

How can this be acheived.

**Update**

After Gilsha suggesstion to change the clipPath circle cy and cx to 0, below is the result.

[image]

Comment: <g> elements don't clip unless you've attached a clip-path to them.

Comment: Do you have an image of the expected view?

Comment: @Gilsha I just don't want the circle to be clipped.

Comment: @RobertLongson I haven't attached any clip-path to the <g>, the circle clip-path is only clip-path I am using in my code,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the group element. If you want the image to be placed at top left of rectangle as mentioned in question, you should set cx and cy attribute of clip path circle as 0.

```html
<svg>
<defs>
   <clipPath id="empImgClip">
      <circle r="53" cy="0" cx="0"></circle>
   </clipPath>
</defs>
<g>
<rect width=400 height=130 fill="#b4975a" stroke-width=1 stroke="#cccccc" rx=60></rect>
<image height=110 width=110 href="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/square-xxl.png" clip-path="url(#empImgClip)"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Gilsha, but as so can see the full circle is not visible. I wanted the full circle to be visible.